# dojo.fadeOut multiple nodes?

Tags: javascript, dojo

In Dojo you would fade out the `<div id="killme"></div>` like this:

```
var fadeArgs = {
  node: "killme",
  duration: 800,
  onEnd: function(){
    dojo.style("killme", "display", "none")
  }
};
dojo.fadeOut(fadeArgs).play();
```

But how to fade-out multiple divs with the most small amout of code possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as lines of code are concerned, a for loop is not that bad...

```
function fadeNode(nodeId){
  var fadeArgs = {
    node: nodeId,
    duration: 800,
    onEnd: function(){
      dojo.style(nodeId, "display", "none")
    };
  };
  dojo.fadeOut(fadeArgs).play();
}

dojo.forEach(['killme', 'killhim'], fadeNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them into one div (container) and fade-out container.

Answer (score 1):

Dojo can chain and combine effects together, so even if they're not in the same div they can fade at the same time.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/Animation.html#chaining-and-combining-animations